# How to use \def recursively to format equations differently using macros?

Tags: math-mode, macros, equations

I am defining equations in a LaTeX file at the start and want to reuse these in different formats throughout a book and `beamer` presentation. I am trying to have the equations defined as below but it does not work. Is there a solution to this?

```
\def \eqnew#1#2
{ 
  \def \eqd#1{\\[#2\\]}
  \def \eql#1{$#2$}
  \def \eqe#1{\begin{equation}#2\equation}
}  

\eqnew{newton}{F = m a}

\eqnew{mass}{m = \rho v a}

%this does not work

\eqenewton

\eqlmass
```

Comment: `\expandafter\def\csname eqd#1\endcsname{...}`, but I think there are better ways to construct content, e.g. using  `glossaries` Especially you don't get much advantage from the `\eqe...` macro

Comment: beware white space: with `\def\eqnew#1#2 {...` then there _has_ to be a space token after the second argument,

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\eqnew[2]{%
  \@namedef{eqd#1}{\[#2\]}%
  \@namedef{eql#1}{$#2$}%
  \@namedef{eqe#1}{\begin{equation}#2\end{equation}}%
}  
\makeatother

\eqnew{newton}{F = m a}

\eqnew{mass}{m = \rho v a}

%this does work

\begin{document}

\eqenewton

\eqlmass

\end{document}
```